# BrowserMobProxy and Selenium Grid

Tags: bmp

I have a problem with BMP and Se Grid. When I run tests on the local machine I can intercept all responses, but when I switch to Se Grid I cant get any responses. What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Test setUp:
    Proxy proxy = app.getProxyHelper().getProxy();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    ....
    public ProxyHelper(Application manager) throws Exception{
        this.manager = manager;
        server = new ProxyServer(0);
        server.start();
        mylogger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);

```
    server.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor(){
        @Override
        public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
            mylogger.info("" + request.getRequestLine());
            post = "" + request.getRequestLine();
            request.removeHeaders("User_Agent");
        }
    });
    server.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void process(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
            lastStatusLine =  ("" + response.getStatusLine());
            lastResponceCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            try{
                int code = getLastResponseCode();
                checkWithRegExp(code);
            } catch(Exception e){}
            finally {
                server.clearDNSCache();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for help in advance!